# Как вручную вызвать перерисовку страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, extjs

На странице есть два элемента, которые лежат на одной панели и меняют друг друга по клику через `Ext.get('myPanel').setVisible(bool);`. Суть в том что при изменении размеров окна размеры компонентов пересчитываются и тот элемент, который скрыт теряет свои размеры и ломается. Как по клику вручную воспроизвести эту перекомпоновку снова? Или можно сделать что-то еще?

Comment: Сложно сказать без примера кода + непонятно что значит "теряет размеры и ломается". Возможно, стоит использовать систему layout, для позиционирования элементов

Comment: Должным обрзом, не указаны размеры по умолчанию. Вот и ломается.

Comment: В процентах указаны. Как еще что бы заполняло все свободное пространство

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи DevTools от Chrome и JQuery нашел суть проблемы: из-за того что при расчете размеров элемент не отображался ему давали ширину в `0%`, так у меня сломалось 3 компонента (тот что скрыл и два вложенных). Решение напрашивается само собой. При клике, после всех махинации с отображением задаем ширину в процентах (или высоту, смотря как вас):

```
$("#myPanel").css("width", "100%");
```

В итоге браузер видит процентное обозначение и считает ширину заново и исправляет отображение.